# Vue route not being registered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to add a new route to an existing web app:

This is the entry point:

```
// main.js
import router from './router';

... etc

new Vue({
  router,
  ... etc
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

This is the router:

```
// router/index.js
import AffiliateLinks from '../modules/affiliate_links/AffiliateLinks.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
... etc
  {
    path: '/affiliate-links/client',
    component: AffiliateLinks,
    meta: {
      restricted: 'CLIENT',
    },
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  ... etc

  // check routes restricted by distribution channel
  if (to.meta?.restricted && !to.meta.restricted.includes(store.state.user.access.distribution_channel)) {
    next({ path: '/' });
    return;
  }

  // user is logged in, allow requested routing
  next();
});

export default router;
```

// This is the parent component:

```
// AffiliateLinks.vue
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row align-content="space-between">
      <h3>String Here</h3>
      <v-btn @click.stop="showAffiliateLinksModal = true" />
    </v-row>
    <AffiliateLinksModal v-model="showAffiliateLinksModal" @close="showAffiliateLinksModal = false" />
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import AffiliateLinksModal from './AffiliateLinksModal.vue';
export default {
  name: 'AffiliateLinks',
  components: {
    AffiliateLinksModal,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showAffiliateLinksModal: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

// This is the child component:

```
// AffiliateLinksModal.vue
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="value" max-width="450px">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn @click.stop="$emit('close')">String Here</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AffiliateLinksModal',
  props: ['value'],
};
</script>
```

It all looks straight forward, but when I inspect Vue dev tools, I can't see the new route, and when I click on the component such as

```
<v-card :to="url">
  ... etc
</v-card>
```

nothing happens.

Comment: There is no [router-view](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#router-view) in your code. Though you maybe just omitted it here

Comment: Hi, router-view is indeed there, and it's been working alright with at least a dozen other routes

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I called it a day, and committed my changes to remote.
That is when I noticed that the changes made to the router were not there.
I could see the changes in my text editor, and in Git local working changes, but they would not be pushed to remote.

Worth noting: I deleted the local repo, and re-cloned in the same spot, but the problem persisted.

I created an ad-hoc folder and the problem was gone...